# Adding exta numeric parameter after slash in single post

Tags: wordpress

I have single post URL for example

http://www.example.com/single-post

I want to add numeric parameter after post slug like this

http://www.example.com/single-post/1

http://www.example.com/single-post/2

http://www.example.com/single-post/

I have tried many thing. None of its working..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check`add_query_arg()` and  [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but you should consider to **add query arg** at the end of the url instead of what you asked for.

Query args looks like this: `http://www.example.com/single-post?post_number=1`.

```
<?php 
/* We Add query args at the end of the url 
* If you click Single post 1 your url should be like:
* http://www.example.com/single-post?post_number=1
*/
$singlePost_1 =  esc_url( add_query_arg( 'post_number', '1' ) ); 
$singlePost_2 =  esc_url( add_query_arg( 'post_number', '2' ) );  ?>

<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>">Single post</a>
<a href="<?php echo $singlePost_1; ?>">Single post 1</a>
<a href="<?php echo $singlePost_2; ?>">Single post 2</a>
```

### How to use query args

You can get query args with `$_GET['var_name']`, but you should keep in mind using esc_url() when you get the final result to sanitize the url.

```
$postNumber = $_GET['post_number'] != null ? esc_url( $_GET['post_number'] ) : '';
```

When url has `?post_number=2` at the end `$postNumber` will be `2`

Read more here about [add_query_arg()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) [esc_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url)

Hope this helps.